# Can I mark a GIT remote as read only?

Tags: git, github

I have read/write access to a repo on GitHub.  I have a local clone of that repo.  I'd like to be able to pull changes from that remote, but I should never push changes to it.

Is there a way I can mark the remote as read-only so I never accidentally type in the wrong command and push to it?

Comment: Is it a public repo, that you could just clone via the (read-only) git protocol?

Comment: On github ui under repo settings you get an option to archive and read-only. it serves well

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You could  shut off default pushes via

```
git config push.default nothing
```

or for stronger protection on a specific remote you could break pushes to that remote entirely by e.g.

```
git config remote.origin.pushurl "you really didn't want to do that"
```

Comment: "git config remote.origin.pushurl "you really didn't want to do that"" -- I love that idea.  Thanks.  Turning off default pushes wouldn't be ideal since I do want to push to other locations.

Comment: git config remote.origin.pushurl "you really didn't want to do that" has blocked all the pushes in all branch. What to do? How can you reove read only

Comment: @RajeshKumar just delete the config item.

Answer (score 22):

```
git remote set-url origin --push "hey, stop pushing"
```

Note that the following removes an explicitly configured push URL, but then pushes will use the fetch URL, so not what you want:

```
git remote set-url origin --delete --push ".*"
```

Comment: You rather meant: `git remote set-url origin --push "hey, stop pushing"` (or at least that's how it worked for me)

Comment: oops, you're totally right, I just edited the answer to fix this, thanks for the correction

Comment: How is this different from @jthill answer above?