# Make a git commit unpushable to Subversion?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I use git locally, and git-svn to work with a shared Subversion repository. I have a local branch with some parameter changes that are relevant to my test environment, but that I would never want to share with everyone else. Right now the way I'm doing that is by having a local branch with that parameter commit. However, I'd like to make sure I never accidentally commit that branch to SVN.

Is there a way I can flag this commit (or branch) to make git svn dcommit yell at me first? Or maybe a hook that would check so that, say, I can only git svn dcommit from master?

Comment: An easy way is just to clone your git svn repository. Then you'll have a repos that does not know about svn, do whatever you want there, and push to your git svn repos when ready to dcommit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to wording, I missed a similar question desiring the same idiot-proofing; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9330342/20723) sets up a shell configuration that prevents `git svn dcommit` from being run on any branch but master.

Answer (score 0):

you could try [Can I mark a GIT remote as read only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10270189/717355) which prevents writing to a remote. I haven't checked if a branch can be tweaked in a similar manner.

Comment: This looks like it would work if I were pushing to a git remote instead of using svn dcommit, but this might be the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["Cherry Picking"](http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Using_Git_Cherry_Pick) for this, just cherry pick an old commit containing only the common config values.